# Shuttering Audio issue in Android

Tags: java, android

I am a newbie to Android Programming , I have been developing a Media App which can Play , Pause a audio and Use Seekbar to manipulate with Volume and media current location .When I run the app ,I have  shuttering of audio after adding the Seekbar progress value to MediaPlayer.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
AudioManager audioManager;
boolean isPlaying;
public void songPlay(View view)
{
    if(isPlaying) {
        mediaPlayer.start();
        isPlaying = false;

    }
}
public void songPause(View view)
{
    mediaPlayer.pause();
    isPlaying = true;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.nfy);
    isPlaying = true;
    audioManager= (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    int maxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    int currentVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.volumeBar);
    seekBar.setMax(maxVolume);
    seekBar.setProgress(currentVolume);
    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, progress, 0);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });


    final SeekBar scrubber = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.playBar);
    scrubber.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
    new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            scrubber.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
        }
    },0,1000);

    scrubber.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            if(mediaPlayer!=null && fromUser)
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost there, try to replace your `onProgressChanged` with the following.

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            if(fromUser) {
              mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi @AdarshJayakumar if my answer helps to solve you question, can you please accept my answer?

Comment: Done !! Thanks for your answer anyway